# Checking git commit message using commit-msg hook

Tags: git, githooks

I am trying to achieve following structure for git commit msg:

```
Description one line
Type:   Internal / Bugfix / New Feature / Enhancement
Jiras:  XXX
Any text
```

This is my commit-msg file:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -x

MSG="$1"
#MATCH="(?s)(.{4,}[\r\n]Type:(\s*| )?(Internal|Bugfix|New Feature|Enhancement)[\r\n]Jiras:(\s*| )?((PRODUCTS|SYSDEV|LOCSRV|LTESYS|SRD|WIFI|MCU|SLBL|GNSS|SYSTOOL)-[0-9]{1,}(, )?){1,}([\r\n].*)?)"
MATCH="\s*[\r\n]Type:(\s*| )?(Internal|Bugfix|New Feature|Enhancement)[\r\n]"
echo $MATCH
value=$(cat $MSG)
echo "$value"

if [[ ! "$value" =~ $MATCH ]]; then
    echo "Your commit message is in wrong format"
    exit 1
fi
```

I always get a wrong format message for example for the commit message below which is correct:

```
Add function
Type: Internal
Jiras: SRD-474
Problem:
```

Comment: Try: `match=$'[\r\n]Type:(\s*| )?(Internal|Bugfix|New Feature|Enhancement)[\r\n]'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep

```bash
#!/bin/bash -x

MSG="$1"
#MATCH="(?s)(.{4,}[\r\n]Type:(\s*| )?(Internal|Bugfix|New Feature|Enhancement)[\r\n]Jiras:(\s*| )?((PRODUCTS|SYSDEV|LOCSRV|LTESYS|SRD|WIFI|MCU|SLBL|GNSS|SYSTOOL)-[0-9]{1,}(, )?){1,}([\r\n].*)?)"
MATCH="^Type:\s*(Internal|Bugfix|New Feature|Enhancement)$"
echo $MATCH
value=$(cat $MSG)
echo "$value"

if ! echo "$value" | grep -E "$MATCH" ; then
    echo "Your commit message is in wrong format"
    exit 1
fi
```